# What's causing initctl stop to fail?

Tags: linux, process, services, sysvinit, upstart

I have an upstart process which terminates all child processes during post-stop:

`post-stop exec killall my-process & exec sleep 10`

This works as expected, however I'm unsure of the following two cases:

If the killall process isn't run as a background process:

`post-stop exec killall my-process && exec sleep 10`

Or if I remove the sleep process altogether:

`post-stop exec killall my-process`

In these two scenarios if i run initctl stop, it returns the following error:

`initctl: Job failed while stopping`

Why does the first example stop as expected, whilst the other two examples fail to stop properly?